# My $(document).on("click") function works on my front page but not on any other page when viewed on ipad

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Here is my code, I have it to where it avoids the hover problem on ios by identifying it and turning it into a click function rather than hover.  The menu dropdowns open up and when i click outside the dropdown it closes. but it only works on the front page and not any other page. I have no clue why.

here is a link but to understand the problem you should open it up on an ipad on landscape view. click on the menu and see the dropdowns open up then close when you click outside the dropdown, then go to another page and try doing the same thing.

http://heavenlysplendor.org/home

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
  (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || 
  (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
     $(".dropdown").on("click", function () {
       $dropdownContent.removeClass("dropdown-content-show");
       var $clickedDropdownContainerElements = $(this);
       var clickedDropdownContents = 
$clickedDropdownContainerElements.find($dropdownContent);
    clickedDropdownContents.addClass("dropdown-content-show");
  });
  $(document).on("click", function(event){
      var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
      if($trigger !== event.target && 
!$trigger.has(event.target).length){
      $dropdownContent.removeClass("dropdown-content-show");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you also include the PHP code to embed this script into the HTML? Is it in footer.php, header.php or enqueued in functions.php?

Comment: If you look at the console errors on other pages, you get this error many times `ERROR calling method 'setClassToggle()': Invalid element supplied.` while it doesn't occur on homepage.